# Writing a ROS command-line utility in C++ - what is the difference compared to writing a ROS node in C++?

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Howdy folks

So far I have written ROS nodes in C++ and invoked them in launch files.

Now I want to write a ROS command-line utility for off-line processing rosbag files in C++ (using the rosbag C++ API), which doesn't interact with any other nodes per se.

More in particular I want to write a utility that looks for camera_info messages in a given bagfile and change camera calibration and distortion parameters.

**My question is: Do I write a command-line utility just like I would write a node in C++, within the catkin build framework? What's different between writing a utility and writing a node in C++? Does anyone know of a good C++ example that I can learn from?**

Thanks in advance

Galto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239924/writing-a-ros-command-line-utility-in-c++----what-is-the-difference-compared-to-writing-a-ros-node-in-c++-?/) by [Galto2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/22578/galto2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, everything is the same. At the end you just write a normal C++ program using the ROS libraries. Just skip actually connecting to anything, e.g., no need for NodeHandles, etc.

For your specific problem: `rosbag filter` might already be able to do that, so you won't need to write any specific utility.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Galto2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/22578/galto2000/) on 2016-07-20**:
Thanks for your reply and pointing me to rosbag filter - I'll give it a try.

**Comment by [Galto2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/22578/galto2000/) on 2016-07-21**:
Worked like a champ - thanks again!